# Is there way to have bootstrap one column height equal to two columns vertically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a layout with bootstrap where I need one column to be equal to two columns vertically. I think it would be better understood if you take a look at visual representation. 
Also, I want it to be responsive to the next column would wrap below this layout on smaller devices.

[image: Layout]

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow will pay you for your effort with attention

Comment: Well, I've created this with css grids but I want to have this with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to structure your HTML accordingly.
Try this code snippet.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Left Column</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Right Column Row 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Right Column Row 2</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It worked, the html is a bit tricky that's why I was not getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

CSS:

```
<style>

div{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.row, .container{
    border: none;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">4</div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method.